# How to convert a gray8_view_t to a rgb8_view_t by using boost::gil and create a rgb8_image_t object from it?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil

Since boost::gil does not support gray8_view_t writing for the BMP format, I want to convert gray8_view_t to rgb8_view_t. Here is what I've tried so far.

`auto rgb_view = boost::gil::planar_rgb_view(width, height, pixels, pixels, pixels, width);`

pixels contains the raw pixels from the gray8_view_t object, so I let r=g=b=pixels. But `boost::gil::write_view(ofstream, rgb_view, boost::gil::bmp_tag())` gives me an empty image. Any idea?

**Update:**
By using sehe's example code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daa0735f774b727f, I was able to get the color conversation to compile with `color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_view_t>`. But it does not compile when I use `boost::gil::write_view` to create an image file from the return value of `color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_view_t>`. My guess is I will have to create an actual rgb8_image_t object from the return value. How can I convert the return value of `color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_view_t>` to an actual rgb8_image_t object? Thank you!

```
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <fstream>
namespace gil = boost::gil;

int main()
{
        std::ifstream in("gray8_image_t_sample.jpg", std::ios::binary);
        gil::gray8_image_t img;
        gil::read_image(in, img, gil::jpeg_tag());
        gil::gray8_view_t gv = gil::view(img);
        std::ofstream ofs1("test_image.png", std::ios::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        gil::write_view(ofs1, gv, gil::png_tag()); // This works

        auto rgbv = gil::color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_view_t>(gv);
        std::ofstream ofs2("test_image.bmp", std::ios::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        gil::write_view(ofs2, rgbv, gil::bmp_tag()); // this does not compile
}
```

One of the error messages I'm getting

```
\boost\gil\color_base_algorithm.hpp(170,76): error G1A4676F8: no member named 'layout_t' in 'boost::gil::image<boost::gil::pixel<unsigned char, boost::gil::layout<boost::mp11::mp_list<boost::gil::red_t, boost::gil::green_t, boost::gil::blue_t>, boost::mp11::mp_list<std::integral_constant<int, 0>, std::integral_constant<int, 1>, std::integral_constant<int, 2>>>>, false, std::allocator<unsigned char>>' [clang-diagnostic-error]
```

[Here is the gray8_image_t file I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE0nR.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daa0735f774b727f?

Comment: Actually, I use `gil::any_image_view<gil::gray8_view_t, gil::rgb8_view_t> image_view;` to store the image data. I have tried `auto rgbv = gil::color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_view_t>(image_view);`. But gil::color_converted_view does not compile when the argument has an any_image_view type. How can I convert any_image_view to gray8_view_t? I've tried boost::get<gray8_view_t>(image_view) but it does not work

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting `boost\gil\extension\dynamic_image\image_view_factory.hpp(160,28): error GB4E3CEB1: excess elements in struct initializer [clang-diagnostic-error]
          return result_type{color_converted_view<DstP>(src, _cc)};`

Comment: Using any_image_view is adding complexity that you probably don't need. This page details how to use it with GIL algorithms: [To perform an algorithm on any_image_view, put the algorithm in a function object and invoke it by calling `apply_operation(runtime_view, algorithm_fn)`;](http://boostorg.github.io/gil/doc/html/reference/classboost_1_1gil_1_1any__image__view.html#:~:text=To%20perform%20an%20algorithm%20on%20any_image_view%2C%20put%20the%20algorithm%20in%20a%20function%20object%20and%20invoke%20it%20by%20calling%20apply_operation(runtime_view%2C%20algorithm_fn))

Comment: From your example code, `gil::rgb8_image_t rgbi(rgbv.width(), rgbv.height());` does not create a rgb8 image with the raw pixel data. How can I actually create a rgb8_image_t object that has the raw pixmap from the return value of `color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_view_t>(gv)`? Thanks for your help! I'm very new to C++ and Boost::gil

Comment: Oh yeah that last line was just a left-over. Are you saying you got the color conversion to work then? Perhaps it is time to update your question with the actual code and precisely what you are stuck on.

Comment: Because of the complexity of `any_image_view`, I decided to use rgb8_view_t as the only image view type to store image data and use `color_converted_view` whenever I need to convert gray8_view_t to rgb8_view_t. I've updated my question. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the remaining problem was merely a misspecified template argument, `color_converted_view` expects a destination pixel type:

```
#include <boost/gil.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/bmp.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png.hpp>
#include <fstream>
namespace gil = boost::gil;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("gray8_image_t_sample.jpg", std::ios::binary);
    gil::gray8_image_t img;
    gil::read_image(in, img, gil::jpeg_tag());
    gil::gray8_view_t gv = gil::view(img);
    gil::write_view("input.png", gv, gil::png_tag());

    auto rgbv = gil::color_converted_view<gil::rgb8_pixel_t>(gv);
    gil::write_view("output.png", rgbv, gil::png_tag());
    gil::write_view("output.bmp", rgbv, gil::bmp_tag());
}
```

With the resuling files:

| name | preview |
| --- | --- |
| [input.png](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/234acb61-9254-4023-95ed-82f6143e65b3/input.png) | [image] |
| [output.png](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/ed256e84-ba5a-4a96-8e40-4878b8878bc4/output.png) | [image] |
| [output.bmp](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/53fac160-4ec4-48fa-95be-1243d0536329/output.bmp) | [image] |

Comment: Cheers. Welcome to stackoverflow. Don't forget to vote and accept (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)